# if a Facebook user already authorised my app, can I pass it on to my webView?

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

When a user hits the Like button in my webView (even after he/she authorised the native Facebook integration for the app), The webView keeps bringing up the Facebook login form. 
This only means the session of the app and the one of the webView are obviously different ones.
Any idea of how to share the session cookies?